# How to add sort with custom comparer to Fluent nHibernate collection mapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I need to rewrite the following collection mapping using Fluent nHibernate.

```
<set name="Contracts" sort="ContractComparer, ActualsModels" inverse="false" lazy="true" cascade="all">
  <key column="EV_PROJECT_LEDGER_KEY"/>
  <one-to-many class="Contract"/>
</set>
```

Specifically I don't know how to map the `sort="ContractComparer, ActualsModels"` attribute with my custom comparer class. This is what I have so far:

```
HasMany(x => x.Contracts)
    .Cascade.All()
    .OrderBy("CONTRACT_ID")
    .KeyColumn("EV_PROJECT_LEDGER_KEY");
```

OrderBy only sorts the data coming directly from the database, however I need to keep the collection sorted even after adding new elements. I can achieve this by using the .hbm mapping pasted above however I would like to move to using the Fluent mapping exclusively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the collection to use a List rather than a Set. Then I added the following function to my entity class which inserts new items in the correct order.

```
/// <summary>
/// Inserts inContract and maintains order by ContractId
/// Does not allow duplicates (assuming list is ordered)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="inContract">Contract to insert</param>
/// <returns>True if add was successful and false otherwise</returns>
public virtual bool AddContract(Contract inContract)
{
    ContractComparer contractComparer = new ContractComparer();
    for (int i = 0; i < myContracts.Count; i++)
    {
        int compareVal = contractComparer.Compare(inContract, myContracts[i]);
        if (compareVal == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        //catches case where contract should be inserted at the end of the list
        if (i == myContracts.Count - 1)
        {
            myContracts.Add(inContract);
            return true;
        }
        if (compareVal > 0) continue;
        myContracts.Insert(i, inContract);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The OrderBy in the Fluent mapping ensures that the list is ordered coming out of the database.

```
HasMany(x => x.Contracts)
    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
    .OrderBy("CONTRACT_ID")
    .KeyColumn("EV_PROJECT_LEDGER_KEY");
```

While this works I did like the sort attribute allowed through the hbm.xml mapping file passing the custom comparer class because that maintained the order and did not allow duplicates.